# How to use a timer to stop a long-running function? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, nstimer

I have a function that runs for a long time, and I'd like to give it a cap of 10 seconds if possible. I'd also like to implement a `Cancel` button for the user to press as well.

I tried simply checking the status of a var `abort` while it calculates, but it just continues working. I'm not very skilled with Grand Central `Dispatch` and `timers` and don't know where to go from here.

```
...



var abort = false

@objc func abortCalculations() {
    abort = true
}


func calculate() {
    abort = false

    let _ = Timer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(abortCalculations), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)



    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        while !abort {
            x += 1 // for example, just something that repeats
                    // when this actually finishes, it leaves the dispatch group
        }
    }
}



...
```

I'd like the function `calculate()` to finish when the timer stops it (or when a user presses a button, in the future). Instead, it continues to run and the function `abortCalculations()` is never called.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48029616/1327778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `Timer`, you can use a similar `DispatchQueue` to set your abort flag.

```
var abortFlagItem = DispatchWorkItem(block: {
    self.abort = true
})
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10, execute: abortFlagItem)
```

At any point if you want to cancel, you can call `abortFlagItem.cancel()`

Comment: Actually one more question: I have this in a function that is repeatable, and the timer is carrying over, meaning that if the first function happens to finish in 5 seconds, and the user presses the button to repeat it, it now only has 5 seconds remaining from the first timer. Do you know of a way to cancel the first timing method? My not-smart idea would be to create an array of bools instead of the single abort bool, and each button press starts a new entry in the array. Then each calculation checks if !abort[x]. Not efficient, of course.

Comment: Since `abort` (and `self`) is used by two different threads, can it lead to race conditions?

Comment: @Cristik Yes, it will, when accessing the var `abort`. The compiler might even optimise the given code `while !abort {...}` to `while true {...}`. So, the data race is one issue. We might be inclined to use a function which reads and modifies the var `abort` - however, without synchronisation, it's still a data race - the compiler _might_ just not be able to optimise away the read access (unless the compiler is able to inline the function), which just makes the approach to work "more often".